# Make squares resize based on the size of an array inside a div - css/html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a simple card, where an array creates the number of squares. The objective is that the squares fit the div, no matter the number. Ex: if in the div there are only 2 squares, the size of the squares is bigger to fit the div. If the div have like 5 squares, they should resize to fit inside de div, and so go on.

I spent hours and hours trying to create that i and couldnt.

I have the code in thje editor if anyone want to see it:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kdapqa?file=src/app/app.component.css

When the order array, have like only 1 object, the square should fit the div squares. If the order have two objects. The two squares must be 50% of the div and so go on.

I dont know if i am expalining this right or not, but the squares should be responsive to the div

```css
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#card{
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#background{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #5e8d93;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#cardDescription{
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0;
  right: 5%;
  z-index: 11;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 20px;

}
#squares{

  border-top: 1px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 30%;
  height: 100%;
}

.square{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #1e2023;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<body>


<div id="card">
    <div id="background"></div>
    <p id="cardDescription" color="primary" style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px;color: white;font-weight: bold">
      tittle
    </p>
    <div id="squares">
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
     
    </div>
    <p id="companyName" color="primary" style="text-align: center; font-size: 15px;color: white">
      restaurant
    </p>
  </div>

  </body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The question itself must include the minimum amount of the relevant code required to show the problem, as external links can change or break over time, which makes the question invalid and longer useful to other users. Please see how to create a [MRE] and [edit] your question to add the code in a runnable Stack Snippet if possible using the `[<>]` button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: I will edited right now

Comment: @Fabio100ola can you please share your expected output? Didn't get what you want. It's vague. Define fitting. Like, if you have a div of size 200px by 200px and you have 4 div then each div would be 50px by 50px. But what would be the length of each div, when you've 2 divs or 3 divs? or maybe 5 divs?

Answer (score 0):

```
function fun(){
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("square").length;
    var y = 100/x;
    var myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("square");
    myDiv.setAttribute("style", "width: "+y+"%; height:"+y+"%;");   
}
```

Add this function in the `<script>` tag and change`<body onload="fun()">`

Hope this works

Comment: I will try it! Thanks!